# 10 Day intervals with a overlapping date

Tags: r, date, lapply, posixct

I have a annual data set that I would like to break into 10 day intervals. For example I would like to subset `2010-12-26` to `2011-01-04` create a home range using the x and y values for those dates, then get the next 9 days plus an overlapping date between the subsetted data in this case it would be `2011-01-04` (`2011-01-04 to 2011-01-13`). Is there a good way to do this?

```
library(lubridate)
date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("26-12-2010"), dmy("20-01-2011"), by = "days"), 500)
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000))
```

I separated them by 10 observations, but I am unsure as to how I can do make it more specific to get 10 days instead of just 10 observations.

```
interval_10 <- lapply(
  seq(0, nrow(df), by = 10),
  function(k) df[max(k+1, 1):min(k + 10, nrow(df)), ]
)
```

Thank you

Comment: here is a way to create the desired intervals... `df.interval <- data.frame(from = seq.Date(min(df$date), max(df$date), by = 9),to = from + 9)`. I cannot provide a better answer rigt now, since no desired output is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` through the unique date vector will do the work:

```
t <- unique(date)[seq(from = 1, to = length(unique(date)), by = 9)]
interval_10 <- lapply(
  1:(length(t)-1),
  function(k) df %>% filter(date <= t[k+1], date >= t[k])
)
```